# Asp.net Identity - How to Login Regardless of Discriminator

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, discriminator

Im using asp.net identity and I have a number of user classes that inherit from IdentityUser.

Lets say I have an inheritance chain like:

IdentityUser <- AppUser <- ServiceUser <- ServiceEmployee and ServiceCustomer (which both inherit from ServiceUser).

When trying to create a unified login form whats the best strategy?

If you use the OTB account controller and change the UserManager to use ServiceUser but try to login an account that was registered as ServiceEmployee it will fail because FindAsync() apparently only tries to find based on "ServiceEmployee" in the discriminator field, so if the account was registered as a different "type" it cant be used to login. So this happens with any combination when registered vs login types differ.

Should I update the login action to use multiple UserManagers so that there is a check against each user type or is there some better way to do what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered keeping your identity users and your own application users separate? Meaning `User` is what holds your identity information and `Person` is what the rest of your application uses (and other types such as Employee inherit from). This is how I do it myself. I keep all security/identity stuff completely separate (in separate project/context) and only link my `User` and `Person` entities which works great for me - much easier to maintain and update my security model without affecting the rest of my application and (as much).

Comment: Yeah, thats a good idea, thanks. I guess my thinking didn't go that way because all the articles and documentation around identity talked about using inheritance for different user types. For now, my only solution has been to add separate login forms for different user types. This isn't really ideal, but it works and I dont have to redesign my user classes. I feel like there should be some more 'elegant' solution to this though.